# Reg: tnsping not working sql developer connnecting

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

in our env tnsping on connection string not working, but while connecting through sql developer able to connect to db using tns and network_alias name, but in sql developer also when trying to connect through connect identifier discription address not connecting.

while connecting to sqlplus database
getting below error.
Status : Failure -Test failed: ORA-29048: Unexpected message received.

below is the error getting

```
tnsping TSUAT_SSL.TRA

Used parameter files:
F:\app\client\prt\product\12.1.0\client_5\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

used TNSNAMES adaptor to resolve the alias

Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=ORACLE.DTRA.LOCAL)(PORT=2484)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=TSU)))

TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adaptor error

C:\Windows\system>
```

Comment: "Not working" is totally devoid of any useful information.  Please update you question to provide the following:  A screen shot of your working SQL Dev connection def; a screenshot of your failing SQL Dev connection def; full text of your reference tnsnames.ora entry; full command and output of your failing sqlplus.  No links, paste it all directly into your question.  For the tnsnames and sqlplus, copy the text and paste it with code formatting.

Comment: tnsping at client side not working at server side working fine

Comment: can anyone suggest please

Comment: Please re-read my earlier comment.  I told you there what diagnostics we needed, but you haven't provided.  You do now show one error message.  What did you discover when you googled it? I see from the posted error message that your tnsnames is configured to try to connect on port 2484.  That is very strange, as the default port for the listener is 1521.

Comment: _"tnsping at client side not working at server side working fine"_  Please update your question to show the relevant tnsnames entry from both the client and server.

Comment: Stevens it’s ssl setup so 2484 configured at server side in listener and tnsnames.ora and tnsping at server side working good and database is also connecting from 2484 port but only at client side tnsping not working